# Should AWS SQS message polling be used in a Nodejs + Koa application?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have created a Nodejs + Koa application, that contains my Koa website and an API that receives requests from Angular.js that runs on the Koa website.

I will use the AWS SQS service to push messages from the application. These messages will be handled by an AWS Lambda function. When the Lambda function completes the work, it will push a message to another SQS queue. The Nodejs application will be polling that SQS queue for messages and when there is a message, it will send a status report to the user.

I have red the SQS documentation and it says, that it is not recommended to use long polling in a single thread applications, because it will block the thread.

I was wondering if it is a good idea to use the short polling at a 5 - 10 seconds interval (maybe less)? Is there a chance that this will significantly slow the website performance? Are there best practices for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I would recommend separating the reporting functionality to a different process.(Keeps the concerns separate)

I do not think, even long polling will adversely effect on your application performance.

Whatever SQS says about single threaded application is true, but for a application built on nodejs it does not apply. When you use the receive message api of SQS with the long polling, the wait happens on the server and the client API is asynch.

Nodejs leverages the eventloop mechanism and during the retrieval of messages, other processing can continue. Only when the messages are received on the client, the callback will be invoked and your process will be blocked.

Unless your processing is time consuming, I don't think the overall processing will be adversely impacted.

Comment: Currently I am working on a nodejs module, that will create a child_process. The process will use long pooling to pool for SQS messages and send the message data to the parent process.

Comment: gr8. no real concerns then. I will always advice long polling, saves cost and network bandwidth.